# Button size becomes too small when it is empty

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When there is no text, the button collapses (becomes too small). I am using angular model to bind to button text:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-bind="vm.buttonText" tooltip="{{vm.tooltipText}}" ></button>
```

I donot want to add any CSS styles to correct it, but I want to add a space( ) character when button has no text.
Going through some other similar issues, I came accross ng-bind-html, which involves ngSanitize as dependency. Is all that required to do this, or is there any easier way.. **Again, my requirement is to show space character as button text when text is empty, and this text comes from vm.buttonText .**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a conditional bind:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
        ng-bind="vm.buttonText ? vm.buttonText : '&nbsp;'" 
        tooltip="{{vm.tooltipText}}" ></button>
```

Comment: I think this is the easiest thing to do, as I was looking for a minimal way..
I have accepted your answer ( it will appear when I get 15 reputation points ! :D). thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must to add `&nbsp;`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-bind="vm.buttonText" tooltip="{{vm.tooltipText}}" >&nbsp;</button>
```

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Answer (score 0):

Browser rendered Html has no meaning of white spaces in your html.
Hence to show a blank space in your button text, you must provide html entity corresponding to a blank space which is   . This will insert a space in button text

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-bind="vm.buttonText" tooltip="{{vm.tooltipText}}" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter like this "minimumsize"

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-bind-html="vm.buttonText|minimumsize" tooltip="{{vm.tooltipText}}" ></button>
```

JS:

```
app.filter('minimumsize', function($sce) {
  return function(input) {
    input = input || '';
    var out = $sce.trustAsHtml(input);

    if (input.length < 1) {
      out = $sce.trustAsHtml("&nbsp;");
    }

    return out;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to play between padding and button sizes in css.

Something like that:

First of all set a width and a height to each button. For example

```
/* This is a custom css class for your buttons */
.square{
    padding: 15px; /* must be adjusted later */
    width:50px; /* 50 px is only indicative, it may be any size */
    height:50px;/* 50 px is only indicative, it may be any size */
}
```

Then try it in your browser, press F12 and modify padding in your browser until the buttons with text and the empty ones will have the same size.

This trick worked for me wonderfully but it may not be helpful in general because I did not tested it with Bootstrap. But I suppose that, even with bootstrap, the idea will be similar. Disable some Bootstrap settings in your custom class if they interfer with your style. I hope this will help someone.

Edit: if you notice that your buttons work in Chrome/Edge but not in Firefox, here´s another trick. Suppose you have defined each .square inside a parent .board-row element, then you could apply this fix:

```
.board-row{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* inside the board */
  justify-content: left; /* justify the board left */
}
```

This ensures that the size of the buttons will not change, even in Firefox.